# Dynamic port mapping for ECS tasks

Tags: amazon-ecs

I want to run a socket program in aws ecs with client and server in one task definition. I am able to run it when I use awsvpc network mode and connect to server on localhost every time. This is good so I don’t need to know the IP address of server. The issue is server has to start on some port and if I run 10 of these tasks only 3 tasks(= number of running instances) run at a time. This is clearly because 10 tasks cannot open the same port. I can manually check for open ports before starting the server and somehow write it to docker shared volume where client can read and connect. But this seems complicated and my server has unnecessary code. For the Services there is dynamic port mapping by using Application Load Balancer but there isn’t anything for simply running tasks. 
How can I run multiple socket programs without having to manage the port number in Aws ecs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using awsvpc mode, each task will get its own eni and there shouldn't be any port conflict. But each instance type has a limited number of enis available. You can increase that by enabling eni trunking which, however is supported by a handful of instance types:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-instance-eni.html#eni-trunking-supported-instance-types

Comment: Yes ENI limit was the issue! Thanks